# package com.sun.security.ntlm does not exist

Tags: java

I've jdk1.8.0_25 installed on my system but at the time of maven compiling there is always **package com.sun.security.ntlm does not exist** error occur on ** import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;** line. I've found same problem on web but no one can help me to skip this problem.Once again there is a guva.jar used on the project

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed jdk from official site?

Comment: yes I m pretty sure. by checking **mvn --version** command it shows 
**Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre**

Comment: Is that import in the code you are trying to compile? You know that all "com.sun.*" packages are internal and should not be directly used by custom code? Doing so will cause problems like this one.

Comment: I'm not observing the same issue as you are - using the same version of Java - 1.8.0_25.

Comment: Are you sure you ask maven to compile with java 8 ?

Comment: @Henry you are absulately correct.It's the main problem after removing this unused package, the error is removed thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Although your error is on the NotNull class import, if you really want to work directly with the NTLM classes instead of the Authenticator facilities, you could import anything from the `com.sun.security.ntlm` package as long as you have the corresponding compiled classes in your classpath (files which are not easy to find).