# Java way of validating NTLM authentication via LDAP to retrieve username and domain

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, ntlm

A client has requested an implementation of a simple SSO-like NTLM validator. Therefor I need to find a way to validate if an which user is logged in when trying to connect to a server.

With JavaScript it took me about 5 minutes with this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ntlm

You can define a LDAP Server for the package and the NTLM negotiation will lead to the "DomainName", "UserName", "Workstation" and "Authenticated" values. I've the implementation successfully.

Is there a library or other natives ways to get this done with Java as easy as with a NodeJS-Server?

Some solution I found would need the credentials, which I don't have or don't want to provide. The JavaScript solution runs only with the LDAP Server provided so it's pretty sure I don't need them.

Comment: You don't need LDAP, just JAAS with the NTLM provider.

Comment: EJP is right.  Adding LDAP is just an unneeded layer of complexity. You could use a hacking technique called NTLM Relay, but man...

Comment: Speaking of the nodeJS-Way I don't see any "unneeded layer of complexity" in a 10 line code solution. Maybe this won't be the best way, but with this approach I only have to configure 1 URL and it works like charm... But as mentioned: I haven't found a Java lib doing this

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not completely clear to me, but I'll try an answer for the *native* part and enhance this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401008/7748072) by the same time which is more or less about the same topic.

Starting with JDK 7, we see the following `com.sun.security.ntlm` native package which is

```
$ unzip -l 1.7/jre/lib/rt.jar | grep -i ntlm
 4243  2015-04-10 19:56   com/sun/security/ntlm/Client.class
 1568  2015-04-10 19:56   com/sun/security/ntlm/NTLM$Reader.class
 1831  2015-04-10 19:56   com/sun/security/ntlm/NTLM$Writer.class
 6486  2015-04-10 19:56   com/sun/security/ntlm/NTLM.class
  617  2015-04-10 19:56   com/sun/security/ntlm/NTLMException.class
 3763  2015-04-10 19:58   com/sun/security/ntlm/Server.class
  939  2015-04-10 19:56   com/sun/security/ntlm/Version.class
  ... ...
```

Unluckily this package is not intended to be used directly, as explained in the [Oracle JDK-6982971 bug](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6982971) which states :

> The com.sun.security.ntlm package and classes inside it are not
>   exposed as NON_CORE_PKGS and there not visible to javac.

From there, the *native* solution relies on this workaround : compile your code with all of the com.sun.security.ntlm source files that you can download from [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/), for example [Client.java](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/security/ntlm/Client.java/?v=source), [NTLM.java](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/security/ntlm/NTLM.java/?v=source),.. the `Server.verify` method giving you access to the parameters you mentionned in your question. Please note this debug property could help you (`-Dntlm.debug`).

In this implementation, be aware it won't compile until JDK 1.7 as there is a call to a [String in switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html), although you could easily backport to an earlier Java version.

I recommend using the latest source available as bugs could be hard to track in the (Java 7 for example) [Support Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javase7supportreleasenotes-1601161.html). By the time of writing, at my knowledge the current versions to use are listed in the [OpenJDK JDK-7150092 bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7150092).

I didn't code any server with this method for now, but only an HTTP client around 100 lines, and this demonstrates the technique. One last thing to know, the native classes I'm talking about are not multi-threaded.